# Which datatype in Django model to be used to save HTML5 type "month" in database

Tags: python, django, html

I have a HTML form with field which takes input as month

```
<input type='month' name="last_appraisal" id='txtLastAppraisal' value='2013-12' />
```

In my Django model this field is defined as

```
last_appraisal = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
```

When I try to save this value (received from request.POST) in database then I get format error.

```
last_appraisal = request.POST.get('last_appraisal','')
if last_appraisal != '':
    mymodel.last_appraisal = last_appraisal
    mymodel.save()

ERROR: raise exceptions.ValidationError(msg)
    ValidationError: [u"'2013-01' value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format."]
```

I know I can achieve this by adding a default day(maybe 01) to this input month and then save into the database. And while fetching back this value I can re-format it like "YYYY-MM" and send it back to template.

But I want to know if there's any better way to achieve this. I am using Django 1.5.1 and Python 2.7.

EDITED:
After reading all the responses it is clear that Django doesn't have built-in support for this format. Now I have few choices

1. My way to add day into date field.
2. As suggested by @Odif to take database field as 'CharField'
3. As suggested by @Ghopper21 to create a Custom Django field

My preference will be the choice1 because using this

1. I don't have to write some extra complex code compare to choice3.
2. I get the flexibility to use this field in table searches like 'find all candidates who got their appraisal in Jun 2013' which I loose if I go for chioce2.

Don't know whether my choice is good or bad but considering the size of project and time to complete it I think this will be the best choice. Please comment if you think this is absolutely rubbish or if you are in favor of this approach.

Comment: maybe you should consider writing your own field type by overriding DateField

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues here: Django doesn't have a built-in way to deal with month/year-only dates, and nor does Python.

If you are ok with a convenient way to translate the month/year-only dates into full dates with the day set to 1, but just don't want to have to do this manually in your view code every time, you can encapsulate that logic in a [custom Django widget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/), which is a component for translating between the Django field representation (in this case a DateField) and the HTML input field.

If you need to have the underlying Python representation of the date to be month/year-only in a first class way, I'd suggest looking into the excellent Python library `dateutil`'s `relativedelta` class -- which allows you to specify things like `relativedelta(year=2013, month=12)`. If you want to use that, you'd then have to create a [custom Django model field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/) that translates between `relativedelta` instances and database storage via serialization. You'd then still need a custom widget for the HTML side of things.

Comment: I am not using Django forms, is it possible to use custom Django widget without forms?

Comment: Sure, look up the widget documentation. You can create a widget a use the `render` and `value_from_datadict methods yourself. But at that point you are just essentially creating two translation functions, which you can do however you like if you aren't using a Django form.

Answer (score 1):

Use models.CharField. DateField and DateTimeField expect date and datetime object respectively. Since '2013-01' cannot be coerced into either, then use CharField. Or use integerfield and just post month.

Comment: Yes I can do this.. but this is also a workaround. If I use 'CharField' then i will loose all the benefits of using 'DateField' like  adding two dates, getting difference etc.

Comment: Yes, but you are not using dates anyway.